how to end flask app (e.g. control c) when i close/terminate a tkinter window
I am currently working on a python/flask project. I am using tkinter as a GUI for testing purposes to show variables and use sliders etc. However, I have been stuck on how to terminate both at the same time. Either I would get one of the not terminating after the other one does or i would get a EOFError: Ran out of input
Here is my current code:
### MAIN CODE FOR FLASK APP IS ABOVE ###

def flask_run():
    app.run(port=PORT)


def tk_run():
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("800x600")
    root.title("Telemate GUI")
    root.config(bg="#2c3e50")

    root.mainloop()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    flask_process = Process(target=flask_run)
    flask_process.start()

    root_process = Process(target=tk_run)
    root_process.start()

    flask_process.join()
    root_process.join()


I am using multiprocessing right now but i don't know if this is the best solution to run both tasks at the same time and terminate them (end the program/flask app when I terminate the tkinter) at the same time. Any help will be greatly appreciated

You can modify your code to gracefully terminate both Flask and Tkinter processes at the same time.
    try:
        flask_process.join()
        root_process.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Terminating processes")

        if flask_process.is_alive():
            flask_process.terminate()
        if root_process.is_alive():
            root_process.terminate()

     
        flask_process.join()
        root_process.join()

    print("All processes terminated. Exiting.")

